# Forcibly create new contact when insert new raw contact

Tags: android, android-contacts

According to the official documentation, when there is a new `RawContact` inserted to the contact's database, the system initiates the mechanism of aggregation to find a `Contact` which the inserted `RawContact` will be aggregated with.

In the case of presence similar contact information in the contacts database the inserted `RawContact` will be aggregated with the existing `Contact` and in the case of absence of such information the system will create a new `Contact` and will aggregate the inserted `RawContact` with it.

I have already looked through the `ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions` and `ContactsContract.Contacts.AggregationSuggestions` but haven't found any information which could help me to figure out how to forcibly tell the system to create a new `Contact` when I insert a new `RawContact` in my application.

If anybody knows how to do that, I would be glad to get your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue here, on 4.0 ice-cream-sandwich the SO doesn't trigger the aggregation if I insert a RawContact (with @S.D.'s specifications), however, on lillipop it's doing it after the rawContact gets inserted the second time. wierd ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new contact, insert values for `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE` in `ContactsContract.RawContacts` and get the new row's `_ID`. Then use this `_ID` to fill in `RAW_CONTACT_ID` when inserting contact data to `ContactsContract.Data`.

The new `_ID` in `ContactsContract.RawContacts` is not supposed to be already present, hence no aggregation until corresponding data is inserted/updated in `ContactsContract.Data`.

`ContactsContract.Contacts` is just an auto aggregated table to ease data query. You are not supposed to alter it directly.